# Pivoting data Based on Departments and status columns without displaying nulls

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot-table

We have an problem with pivoting data based on parent and child relation,
For every parent id we may multiple child ids with different status under different departments.
So,we tried to pivot child data based on parentid and child status under each department using the loops.
I have tried to show you the sample data that we have achieved after all manipulations and pivots in sp .But we struck with some issue
where nulls are being displayed between the child ids.

Thanks in advance ,Any help will be appreciated.

Below is the query which shows our actual parent,child relation data

```
Select * into #Actual_data from (
select 1 AS PARENTID,260 AS CHILDID,'C' AS STATUS,'DENTAL' AS DEPARTMENT
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,230,'C','VISION'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,200,'N','VISION'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,530,'N','DENTAL'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,450,'T','VISION'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,300,'T','DENTAL'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,330,'T','DENTAL'
) as a

Select * from #Actual_data
```

After our sp execution we achived this below data

```
Select * into #Sp_data from (
select 'C' AS STATUS, 1 AS PARENTID ,NULL AS VISION_CHILDS,260 AS DENTAL_CHILDS
UNION ALL
select 'C', 1 ,230 ,NULL 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'N',1 ,200,NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'N',1 ,NULL,530
UNION ALL
SELECT 'T', 1 ,450,NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'T', 1 ,NULL,300
UNION ALL
SELECT 'T', 1,NULL, 330
)as a

select * from #Sp_data
```

**Expected Output:**

```
STATUS  PARENTID    VISION_CHILDS   DENTAL_CHILDS
 C          1            230            260
 N          1            200            530
 T          1            450            300
 T          1            NULL           330
```

Answer (score 2):

So, using the built in `pivot` command, you can do this.
As you want a separate row when items are duplicated, you need to create a `row_number` when multiple instances of the same department occur.

```
select Status, ParentId, Vision as VisionChilds, Dental as DentalChilds
from (
    select *, 
        row_number() over (partition by ParentId, Status, department order by ChildId) rn 
    from #actual_data) s
pivot (max(childId) for department in (vision, dental)) p
```